# Reference types on the heap or on in Stack confused?

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference

Just to understand  what's gone under the hood for reference types  and based on article from Eric Lippert http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/04/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-two.aspx  I would like to understand in  depth why this code is working like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyCalleeClass calleeClass =  new MyCalleeClass();
            calleeClass.MyTestProp = "toto";
            MyCallerClass  callerClass = new MyCallerClass();
            callerClass.TestMethod(calleeClass);
            //normally given  that a class it's a reference type this should give a toto 1  
            Console.WriteLine(calleeClass.MyTestProp);


        }
    }

    class MyCalleeClass
    {
        public string MyTestProp { get; set; }
    }

    class MyCallerClass
    {

    public void  TestMethod(MyCalleeClass calleeClass)
    {
           Console.WriteLine("In the caller method");           
           //does this object is created on  the stack or on the heap 
           calleeClass = new MyCalleeClass();
           calleeClass.MyTestProp = "toto 1"; 
           Console.WriteLine(calleeClass.MyTestProp);


    }
    }
}
```

another question if the caleeClass in the testMethod is not created on the stack is there a partiular case where a reference type could be created on the stack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that something is an "implementation detail" means that the actual implementation is not something you should need to know.

So let's deal with the details first:

- When you construct an object of a reference type, that object lives on the heap
- The reference, however, can live a lot of places:

  - As a temporary element on the stack
  - As a variable on the stack
  - As a field of a value type (and not it lives wherever the value type lives)
  - As a field of a reference type (and since the reference type lives on the heap, the fields inside it does too)

But this question actually seems to confuse the following two concepts:

- Passing a reference type parameter
- Passing a parameter by reference

These are two different things, and in the case of your question, the correct statement would be that *you're passing a reference type parameter by value*.

This all starts to get confusing for a lot of people so let's try to look at what is happening here.

In reality, a reference is just a number. It's something that refers to an object somewhere else in memory. Most likely the number is the address (in memory) of that object.

So, after you've constructed the first object here:

```
MyCalleeClass calleeClass =  new MyCalleeClass();
calleeClass.MyTestProp = "toto";
```

let's say that `calleeClass` contains the number (reference) 1234. At address 1234 there lives an object of type `MyCalleeClass`, and the `MyTestProp` property of that object has the value "toto".

Ok, then you pass this reference to that method. Basically, you *give that method a copy of the reference 1234*.

Inside that method you construct *another* object and assign the reference to this object to the same local variable (the parameter), *overwriting* the 1234 reference with, say, 5678. Pointing to your new object.

And now you change the property of *that* object, the new one.

Then you return back to the outer code. Since that code gave the method a *copy* of the reference 1234, *its* reference still has 1234 and points to the original object, with "toto" in the property.

This is what it means to *pass a reference by value*, you give the method a *copy* of the reference value. The code that is calling still has the original reference.

If you want the code that is calling to continue using the *new* reference you need to *pass the reference by reference*. This is also confusing because the two "reference" words here actually mean different things.

- **A** reference is a reference to an object
- Passing **by** reference means to pass *access* to the underlying variable, and not just a copy of its value

---

**TL;DR** Your code behaves the way it does because you're using one object on the outside, and construct and change a new object on the inside, but the outside world does not get back that new object and continues to use the old one.

As for your second question, can a reference type be allocated on the stack, then no. All objects are allocated on the managed heap.

You can allocate something which looks like a reference type on the stack, arrays of primitives/value types, in unsafe code, like this:

```
unsafe void Test()
{
    int* values = stackalloc int[10];
}
```

But this isn't an "array reference type", it's just a pointer to the first of 10 int values allocated on the stack, so it's not the same thing.

Comment: ok the second question is there a particular case where a reference type could  be created on the stack

Comment: `can a reference type be allocated on the stack, then no.` Of course it can, there's [a whole project ongoing to do just that](https://github.com/ltrzesniewski/dotnet-runtime/blob/master/docs/design/features/object-stack-allocation.md). The heap is just as much an implementation detail as the stack is. End of the day, an object might as well live on the moon, we only care about the copy semantics

Comment: @Charlieface So how would I allocate an object on the stack? The document you linked to seems to be a proposal, not already implemented, and this answer is from 2014, obviously things can and will change. The fact that an object could theoretically possibly technically be allocated on the stack is not what I said, I said that you can't do it right now, it is implied that this is because technically nobody implemented support for it.

Answer (score 0):

This can turn into a large discussion.

In your `TestMethod` the `MyCalleeClass` is generated.
 Since this is a class(ref. type) then it's generated on the heap(lets say at address 1000).
Your stack will contain a pointer to address 1000.

At address 1000 you will have another reference to the string you have in your class(a string is also a ref. type that will sit in address 2000 - for this example).

So:

TestMethod's stack will have a pointer to address 1000.
In address 1000 you will have a pointer to address 2000.
In address 2000 you will have a string.

Comment: this seems  a c++ or c style  not c#??

Comment: I’m  talking about C#.. BTW, here’s one tip will help you..A reference type's value is actually an address. A value type's value is its real value. Now when you pass a param to a method, a copy of his value is passed. Now if we are talking about a value type (e.g. int) then a copy of its value is passed and therefore you’re updating a copy. When you pass a reference, then its address is passed. If you want to change his address you need to pass it with the 'ref' keyword. If you change a reference type's field, then it will change since you are working with the real object.

Answer (score 0):

In your main:

callerClass.TestMethod(calleeClass) -> the reference to the calleeClass is copied as an argument

in your TestMethod

calleeClass = new MyCalleeClass  -> the copied reference (argument of the method) is overwritten to reference another object

when the TestMethod call is returned, the reference is not copied back, so you are still referencing the original class in your main.

If you do want the behaviour you suggest, you should specify: TestMethod(**ref** MyCalleeClass calleeClass).